# MSSQL get row 10 - 20

Tags: sql-server

Hi i want to extract the rows of my database for a paginator in my web project.

```
SELECT DISTINCT jtg.JobID, jtg.CreatedOn, ksnr.value as Snr, kkz.value 
as Kennz, kvu.value as Vu, kstr.value as Strecke, kkzvn.value as KennzVN, ttr.jobid1 as messageId 
FROM tbl_one jtg 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two ksnr on jtg.jobid=ksnr.jobid and ksnr.keyid=6 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkz on jtg.jobid=kkz.jobid and kkz.keyid=29 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kvu on jtg.jobid=kvu.jobid and kvu.keyid=15 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kstr on jtg.jobid=kstr.jobid and kstr.keyid=24 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkzvn on jtg.jobid=kkzvn.jobid and kkzvn.keyid=30 
LEFT JOIN tbl_three ttr on jtg.jobid=ttr.jobid2 
WHERE jtg.JobID IN (SELECT words.JobId FROM tbl_four words LEFT JOIN tbl_five keys on words.KeyID = keys.KeyID WHERE keys.Name = 'Schadennummer')
```

This is my normal query, which works fine. Now i want to get onyl the specific rows for example 10 - 20.

```
select * from (select row_number() over(order by jtg.jobid) num,* from 
tbl_Job_Tracking_Generator jtg) a 
where num > 10 and num < 21
```

This query is evry simple and gives me the lines 10-20 but i cant combine it with my main query above. Ive tried many things but cant get it right. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Which SQL Server version do you use?

Comment: Pagination techniques vary depending on your SQL version but most require an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: microsoft development studio 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a column which can be used for sorting your data in [SQL paging with Row_Number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-paging-row_number-sql-server-function.aspx)

Here is a sample

```
;with cte as (
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By jtg.JobID Desc) rn,
    jtg.JobID, 
    jtg.CreatedOn, 
    ksnr.value as Snr, 
    kkz.value as Kennz, 
    kvu.value as Vu, 
    kstr.value as Strecke, 
    kkzvn.value as KennzVN, 
    ttr.jobid1 as messageId 
FROM tbl_one jtg 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two ksnr on jtg.jobid=ksnr.jobid and ksnr.keyid=6 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkz on jtg.jobid=kkz.jobid and kkz.keyid=29 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kvu on jtg.jobid=kvu.jobid and kvu.keyid=15 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kstr on jtg.jobid=kstr.jobid and kstr.keyid=24 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkzvn on jtg.jobid=kkzvn.jobid and kkzvn.keyid=30 
LEFT JOIN tbl_three ttr on jtg.jobid=ttr.jobid2 
WHERE 
    jtg.JobID IN (
        SELECT words.JobId 
        FROM tbl_four words 
        LEFT JOIN tbl_five keys on words.KeyID = keys.KeyID 
        WHERE keys.Name = 'Schadennummer'
    )
)
select * from cte where rn between 11 and 20
```

On the other hand, SQL Server 2012 has introduced [Order By with Offset and Fetch Next for paging](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) in SQL for database developers

Comment: this works for me! thanks but what does the first line of code mean?

Comment: CTE common table expression is introduced first with SQL Server 2005. You can think of it as a subselect. But its main effect is importance is with recursive queries. Please check SQL tutorial http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-server-recursive-query-with-recursive-cte.aspx on recursive queries with CTE on SQL Server. The CTE syntax requires WITH CTE AS ()... so it starts like this. And it should be seperated with previous code by ";"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL 2012,you can use offset and fetch..

```
with
cte
as
(
SELECT DISTINCT jtg.JobID, jtg.CreatedOn, ksnr.value as Snr, kkz.value 
as Kennz, kvu.value as Vu, kstr.value as Strecke, kkzvn.value as KennzVN, ttr.jobid1 as messageId 
FROM tbl_one jtg 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two ksnr on jtg.jobid=ksnr.jobid and ksnr.keyid=6 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkz on jtg.jobid=kkz.jobid and kkz.keyid=29 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kvu on jtg.jobid=kvu.jobid and kvu.keyid=15 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kstr on jtg.jobid=kstr.jobid and kstr.keyid=24 
LEFT JOIN tbl_two kkzvn on jtg.jobid=kkzvn.jobid and kkzvn.keyid=30 
LEFT JOIN tbl_three ttr on jtg.jobid=ttr.jobid2 
WHERE jtg.JobID IN (SELECT words.JobId FROM tbl_four words LEFT JOIN tbl_five keys on words.KeyID = keys.KeyID WHERE keys.Name = 'Schadennummer')
)
select * from 
cte
order by jobid,createdon,value--idea here is to make this order by unique
offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```